# `.htaccess` Redirect Rules - one rule not working, possible clashing issue?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

### Overview

These are the rules I am trying to apply in my `.htaccess` file:

1. Rewrite `foo.co.uk` to `www.foo.co.uk` - *working fine*
2. Rewrite `http://` to `https://` - *working fine*
3. Redirect access to directories/files that do not exist to `index.php` - *working fine*
4. Redirect `https://www.foo.co.uk/bar` to `https://www.foo.co.uk/index.php?location=bar` - *working fine*
5. Redirect `https://www.foo.co.uk/sitemap.xml` to `https://www.foo.co.uk/sitemap.php` - ***not working***

When visiting `https://www.foo.co.uk/sitemap.xml` I am redirected to the root `https://www.foo.co.uk/`.

---

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.foo.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?location=$1 [L,QSA]

#Redirect XML to PHP Sitemap
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap.php [L]
```

---

### Question

The file `/sitemap.php` exists and, when visiting directly, displays exactly what I'm expecting, however visiting `/sitemap.xml` redirects to the homepage.

How can I redirect `/sitemap.xml` to `/sitemap.php` instead of redirecting to the root?

Comment: Does sitemap.xml file exist?

Comment: No, but `sitemap.php` does

Comment: Try changing location of your last rule, keep it in the middile of other rules. Problem solved.

Comment: @Starkeen I put it inbetween the `HTTPS` and invalid directory rules and... it works. Thanks. Post it as an answer and I'll accept mate, cheers.